# What do I have to install to be able to make a C# program that uses the QuickBooks APIs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, quickbooks

I downloaded the QuickBooks SDK installer from [the intuit website](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/quickbooks_desktop/download_the_sdk) and ran it. When it finished installing, it opened a 'getting started' page in my browser, but that was it. I have tried opening a new project in Visual Studio 2017 using the recommended template from the website, but the template called "Intuit QBFC Application in C#" does not appear in the list of available templates.

Where do I go from here? I just want to make a C# program that has QuickBooks capabilities but I'm not sure if I even have the SDK properly installed. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add references interop.QBFC13 from nugetpackage manager
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Interop.QBFC13